# how to stop frequent nocturnal emission

Tags: neurology, urology, neuroscience

My age is 28 . I am male and i am un married
I do not watch any content that may arouse feelings  but still i face the problem of nocturnal emission (without any dream) approximately twice a week

What should i do to get rid of this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I pointed in https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/a/11676, since sperm are short-lived, they must constantly be replenished, so [the testes produce 1,500 sperm per second](http://news.nationalgeographic.com/news/2010/03/100318-men-sperm-1500-stem-cells-second-male-birth-control/). Plus sperm is produced during the whole of the male life. If the dead sperm is not released through sex or masturbation, it will automatically be released by the body.

Some males find that they are more prone to [nocturnal emissions](http://www.soc.ucsb.edu/sexinfo/article/nocturnal-orgasms-and-emissions) during times of less frequent sexual activity because they are not ejaculating as frequently from masturbation or sex with a partner, and in fact — as studies have confirmed — high ejaculation frequency was related to decreased risk of total prostate cancer [(Leitzmann, et al., 2004)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1001/jama.291.13.1578).

### References

Leitzmann, M.F.; Platz, E.A.; Stampfer, M.J.; Willett, W.C. and Giovannucci, E. (2004). *Ejaculation Frequency and Subsequent Risk of Prostate Cancer* JAMA 291(13): pp 1578-1586; DOI: [10.1001/jama.291.13.1578](http://dx.doi.org/10.1001/jama.291.13.1578)

Comment: Is "it will be automatically released" really a hard fact and absolute consequence? My guess is that without reference your goal can be reached by rephrasing that to "frequently *can*" or sth like that?

Comment: "it will automatically be released by the body" is plain wrong, unless you add some time limit e.g. "automatically be released by the body if not manually released for [put some time range here]". (From own experience... went through weeks without any kind of ejaculation, several times.)